# Send Email when As soon as Case spend 24Hrs in Open State

Tags: formula, case, email-alert

Seems like simple requirement that can be done using workflow, but I am having second thoughts that it might not work.

So I am thinking to create a dateTime field to store Start Time when case entered Open state and In workflow check the difference between Now() and this start Time field and if it is more than 24 Hrs then send email.

But my doubt is workflow will only fire if record is edited, which is wrong. I need to keep checking the difference of Now() and Start Time & as soon as it reaches 24 send email.

Is it even possible using workflow or process builder? Or Apex is the way to go?

Answer (score 3):

Create a **`Time-Based Workflow Action`** and have it fire 24 hours after your Datetime field. You can add criteria to make sure the record is still Open, and those will be checked again before the action fires. See also:

> ## [Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)
>
> You can define rules that trigger **[Time-Based Workflow Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_actions.htm&type=0)** off any Date or Date Time field on an Object.
>
> Example Time-Based Workflow:  Generate critical date reminders to remind Opportunity owners when a large Opportunity (amount greater than $1M USD) is 14 days away from the intended Close Date. Use the same rule to notify the executive sponsor and change the ownership of the Opportunity if the Close Date is just 10 days away.

---

> ## [Add a Time-Dependent Action to Your Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5)
>
> Time-dependent actions are executed at a specific time, such as 10 days before a record’s close date. When that specific time passes, the workflow rule re-evaluates the record to make sure that it still meets the rule criteria. If the record does, the workflow rule executes those actions.

Comment: Dangit you're quick.

Comment: Yeah...now i am clear about this....I was thinking it wrong way

Comment: WFR don't retroactively trigger for existing records so if any meet the criteria, no emails will be sent. To achieve that unfortunately, you have to mass update one of the rule criteria fields to FAIL the WFR criteria and then update it again to PASS the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Set up an Escalation Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rules_escalation_create.htm&type=5) to accomplish this goal. Escalation rules provide a configuration-only way to "escalate" a case when certain conditions are met, such as no activity for 24 hours, etc. It allows you to notify a user, assign the case to a new user or queue, and provides an red arrow next to the Case Number that informs people visually that the case is in an escalated status.

Comment: You cannot use escalation rules if there are more than 1, only 1 rule can be active at a time while triggering the rule.